# cocos2d screen size problem in landscape mode

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, anchor, landscape

I have such a problem in my cocos2d application in landscape mode:
When I'm adding a new object inherited from CCNode and add it to layer and after that layer to screen. The maximum position must be 480 on X and 320 on Y in landscape mode. But my object is in position 480 on X when it coordinates are on (220, 0). Anybody know how to solve this problem?? Thanx!

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
CCLayer *layer = [CCLayer node];

//layer.anchorPoint = ccp(1, 1);
//layer.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480, 320);

CCSprite *sp = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"fon.png"];
[layer addChild: sp];

[scene addChild: layer];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: scene];
}
```

Comment: co-ordinates are relative to the parent object, is the CCLayer added with co-ordinates? or did you just add it to the Scene?

Comment: just add it to the Scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the co-ordinates.

x and y are the same on the phone, regardless of orientation.

When the phone is on its side, x = y and y = x.

Try this

```
player1 = [[Player alloc] initWithPosition: CGPointMake(20, 200) )];
```

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example of your code that replicates the problem? Upload your xcode proj (if you can) to somewhere like dropbox.